# error occurs while importing panda in anaconda navigator

Tags: python, pandas

Whenever I'm importing panda as

```
import pandas as pd
```

I'm getting error  as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "<ipython-input-1-7dd3504c366f>",line 1,in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "C:\users\hp\pandas.py",line 5, in <module>
Pd.Series(data,1)
AttributeError:module 'pandas'has no attribute 'Series'
```

Plz help me out... How can I fix it

Comment: do not name your python-script pandas ..

Comment: You named your file `pandas.py`, try renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't name your file the same as a python library (python has a hierarchy of what it refers to if things are names the same). Rename it to something else and it should work.